# Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in....after second page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, fatal-error, wordpress-thesis-theme

I do not know from how long this problem is on my blog but today I noticed it. On homepage of my website if you use page navigation (bottom) to visit next page you will see following error on third page or after second page:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home4/techshal/public_html/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/lib/functions/teasers.php on line 86

I am using Thesis Theme, the code is below where problem is:

```
function thesis_teaser_category($post_count, $post_image) {
    $categories = get_the_category();
    echo '<a class="teaser_category" href="' . get_category_link($categories[0]->cat_ID) . '">' . $categories[0]->cat_name . "</a>\n";
}
```

Third line is line 86 in above code starting with echo. 
This problem is only for index page navigation working well in category and tag pages. 
I deactivated all plugins to solve this but problem not solved.
Sidebar also will be lost.

Comment: Have you looked for an answer on [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/][1]?


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem has been solved, it is a bug in thesis theme. We have to ad 'if' before 'echo'

Answer (score 1):

Go to your phpmyadmin. Select the name of the database which your wordpress mu is using. Go to Search.

At the: Word(s) or value(s) to search for (wildcard: “%”) type: dashboard_blog

Then on the Inside table(s): you have to scroll down and select wp_sitemeta to be inserted in the Search. OK, just click Go.

You will have the search resources above like this:

Search results for “dashboard_blog” at least one of the words:

```
2 match(es) inside table wp_sitemeta | Browse | Delete
```

Click Browse and you will see 2 table. Edit the table name dashboard_blog.

Whatever you see the meta_value is. I don’t remember exactly (may be ERROR and something) but you don’t need to worry. Just delete all and type 1. Yes, just type the word “1″ in the box ONLY.

Finally, click Go. And log in to you WP. See the result.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The original asker said he fixed it (differently).